# Meaning of "Gunning the thing"

Tags: sentence-meaning

I have a difficult problem with understanding the following is sentence:

> "I mean, I wasn't just gunning the thing. I was driving."

Especially this phrase **"gunning the thing"** I misunderstand. 
I cannot find anywhere the good explanation.
I will really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To gun means  to make an engine operate at a higher speed:
You must have been really gunning the engine to get here on time.

Check [here](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/gun)

It may mean: I was not making my car engine to run faster. I was driving. 
Or I was not speed driving.

Comment: From "just gunning the engine", I'd take it the writer meant, "I wasn't sitting motionless in the drivewary (or parking lot or whatever) making the engine run fast, I actually put the vehicle in motion".

Comment: +1 Jay, emphasis on *just* in "just gunning". That is, "merely".